# Trouble aligning text in 100 VH container

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've been stuck on a problem for 6 hours and I need to ask for help. I'm having trouble aligning the text properly inside the first section.

Here is the site so far.

[Inspect Site Here](http://mazurick.com/testo/portfolio_template.html)

Here is the HTML.

```
<section class="intro_description">
   <div class="fix ">
     <h1>Title of Project</h1>
       <p class="paragraph">Dear Stackexchange, this is my section that I am having problems with. I would be very thankful if you could please tell me what I'm doing wrong.</p>
   <div>
</section>
```

I've created a website where the layout is comprised of stacked sections where height and width values of each section are defined using VH percentages to get a specific layout.

This is an example of how a section is defined in the CSS.

```
.intro_description {
height: 70vh;
width: 100%;
background: #FFFFFF;
display: relative;
padding: 40px;
}
```

Inside of the parent container with the class of .intro_description applied is another div with the class of .fix applied. Here's the CSS for that.

```
.fix {

position: absolute;
top:50%;
bottom:10%;
left:12%;
right: 10%;
transform:translate(0%, -50%);
-webkit-transform:translate(0%, -50%);
}
```

Ideally the title and description should align toward the bottom of the viewport with padding that is consistent with the attached image.

[image]

Could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You need to include the relevant, minimal amount of HTML that applies to this here. Your link will change tomorrow and be of no value to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what you want, but anyway: Your class `.fix` has `position: absolute`. This will only work if the parent element has *some* `position` setting (apart from the default `static`). So, first of all, add `position: relative` to `.intro_description`. This won't change the position of `.intro_description`, but will enable the absolute positioning of `.fix`  to be effective.

EDIT:

Addition after comment:

1.) you changed the parent element to `display:relative`, but it has to be `position: relative`

2.) You have two rule for `.fix` (one of them in a media query). Eventually, `.fix` has to have these parameters:

```
.fix {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px !important;
  top: inherit; 
}
```

So it's aligned to the bottom of it's parent element (i.e. above the subsequent `section`), without being stretched in height by a `top` setting. Whether you want to keep the `transform: translate(0%, -50%);` setting (which moves this block up by 50% of its own height), is a matter of taste.

Comment: I appreciate your comment and suggestion. I understand the confusion. I edited the post. Please see the attached files. I'm trying to accomplish the positioning of the elements like the attached layout.                                  [link](http://mazurick.com/testo/Archive.zip)

Comment: Sorry, I just don't have the ability to post more images. I need more points.

Comment: This is an image that was contained in the zip. Sorry. [link](http://mazurick.com/testo/img/mobile.png)